# Bootstrap 4 - Show Text on sm or bigger, show FontIcon Always

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive-design

In my tabbed interface, I use .nav - I want the FontIcon to appear Always but the Text only on bigger than sm

The below shows the Icon on XS but Text on all others

```
 <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link active" href="#news" data-toggle="tab">
          <div class="d-sm-none"><i class="fas fa-newspaper" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          <div class="d-none d-sm-block">News</div>
     </a>
 </li>
```

If I do

```
  <i class="fas fa-newspaper" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <div class="d-none d-sm-block">News</div>
```

It causes the Icon and the Text to be on different lines

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Instead of `d-sm-block`, you can do `d-sm-inline`.

```html
<a class="nav-link active" href="#news" data-toggle="tab">
    <i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i>
    <div class="d-none d-sm-inline">News</div>
</a>
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/5z8jxek2/10/